# Error checking for strInput to notify user of an input too large for the program?

Tags: c, error-handling, char

I'm simply trying to implement some error checking in my program.

The program converts strings that are 100 characters or less to words that look like the following hello->hElLo. So every other letter is capitalized. So I simply want to add a statement that tells the user the input is too large and asks them to re-enter a word. Here is what I have, but it just outputs `To large.` no matter what is entered, then quits the program.

```
int main(){
/*Read word from the keyboard using scanf*/
char strInput[100];
printf("Input word that is 100 characters or less: \n");

scanf("%s", strInput);
/*Call studly*/
studly(strInput);
/*Print the new word*/
if (strInput > 100){
    printf("To large.");
}
else{
printf("%s", strInput);
}


return 0;
}
```

This is just the main function but I think the only thing I need to do is change my `if` and `else` statements. Just not sure how to check size of `char strInput[100]` in the `if` statment. Also let me know if there is a simple way to handle spaces. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `if (strInput > 100)` is not the way to test a string length. It is looking at the string location in memory. Anyway it's not use checking *after* the input: that's too late. You must restrict the input in the first place, either with something like `scanf("%99s", strInput);` or by using `fgets()`.

Comment: You need to use `fgets` and then check that the buffer is full, but doesn't have a newline at the end. BTW `if(strInput>100)` just checks whether the pointer value is greater than 100, which on most systems will always be true. I think you meant `if(strlen(strInput)>100)`, but that won't solve your problem.

Comment: Okay, great thanks. Yeah looks like using `fgets` worked. That allows a large input but only outputs up to the 100 character max. Thanks! Anyway to check for spaces?

Comment: That's a new question. But `strchr()` might help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fgets` and `strchr` to check if the string contains a trailing newline:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char strInput[100], *ptr;

    printf("Input word that is 100 characters or less: \n");
    fgets(strInput, sizeof strInput, stdin);
    if ((ptr = strchr(strInput, '\n')) == NULL) {
        printf("Too large.\n");
    } else {
        *ptr = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", strInput);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I ended up using `fgets` this seems to be the best way to go about checking for errors. Still not sure about handling spaces, but for this assignment it's not required. Thanks everyone for your help!